# Registration script in php hashing passwords

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning PHP and am at a point where I have successfully managed to insert data into my database and it redirects me back to my registration form so I am happy at this point, I am just looking at ways to add the passwords into the database as a hash and to salt it it also.

Where in my code do I begin doing this, I am not looking for an answer or somebody to do it for me I just need some advice.

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

// escape variables for security
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

$sql="INSERT INTO users (username, password, first_name, last_name, email )
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
    header ('Location: /register.php');



?>
```

Comment: [**Use `password_hash`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.password-hash.php) , that should definitely be the only thing you should use. It takes care of a lot of it for you. Also, use prepared queries over escaping things manually.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, is `password_hash` better than using `sha1`?

Comment: @LinkinTED YES, the fact you're asking that question indicates you should definitely use it too :) SHA1 is not designed for security, it's designed for verification, you should _never_ use SHA1 for security - only for verifying data transfer (for example - after you download a large file and you want to make sure that the data downloaded correctly).

Comment: And if you don't have PHP version >= 5.5.0, you can use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So from my script above, would I be using password_hash there? I am a little confused by the php documentation you see

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, thank you! I definitely see the benefits of this function, however my server doesn't support it (yet).

Comment: @LinkinTED change servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `password_hash` to hash your password.

It will use the best algorithm available and be upgraded in the future.

[More infos here.](http://www.php.net//manual/fr/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Hey thanks for answering my post, I have read through the manual but I am little stumped in my code above as to where i would integrate password_hash or something similar. I used MD5 in an old script once before but that was straightforward.

Comment: @user3725879 go ask in the php room here.